# I'm receiving this error: Cannot resolve symbol: "@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.TextButton"

Tags: android

I'm a noob - one month learning Kotlin and android studio (Version 3.6.3 on Windows 10). I'm trying to setup a really simple project to experiment with Material Design Widgets using Themes and many kinds of widgets.
I've place the following line at the start of my styles.xml file.

```
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
```

I've started by playing with buttons and successfully added one Material design button styled as follows in activity_main.xml:

```
    style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button"
```

But when I add a second button styled with:

```
    style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.TextButton"
```

I get the unresolved symbol error.
What am I missing or doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes.you skip. instead this

```
style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button"
...
style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.TextButton"
```

set this:

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"

style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
```

Comment: Thanks so much - that did it!

Comment: No problems bro